# Which one is more appropiate: Chatroom vs Chatraum

Tags: word-usage, usage

When referring for example to the chats of these network of sites (Stack), which one is more appropiate: Chatroom vs Chatraum?
Chatraum is German, but it seems more popular the term chatroom (loanword).

Is correct to use both?

Comment: Chatraum sounds about as silly as Washing Maschine - that is, *very silly*, sorry. Better not use that.

Comment: Or "Internetz," as used by some Germans. Sorry, folks, but every sane person will laugh at you when using that vocabulary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for clarification: *[Chatraum](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Chatraum)* can be found in the Duden, so it is legit.

A very cursory Google search gave me quite a few hits, but as I see it, they are targeting a somewhat, hm, how should I put it … A slightly low-brow crowd which may be less familiar with English and technical terms than the average user.

I personally would choose *[Chatroom](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Chatroom)* (capitalized!) in 99 % of all cases, except perhaps with a few elderly relatives because I’d have to translate only one word (ok, and the entire concept, but I digress). With a reasonably tech-savvy crowd, I highly recommend the full anglicism — if only to not be seen as part of the user group mentioned in the paragraph above.

In a colloquial context, you might as well abbreviate it as *Chat*, thus eliminating the dilemma altogether.

Comment: Fully agree. Could [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5fMO4.jpg) support your answer?

Comment: @Clijsters I definitely feel so!

Answer (score 4):

I never saw the term *Chatraum* being used by a reputable website. Websites designed for children tend to translate every anglicism and loanword into German. Thus rather weird terms like *Chatraum* can be found throughout the web.

So, in this example and probably in many others, you should stay with the English terms.