# “Channel” in German in the context of chatting, Teamspeak, etc

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am German.

Consider programs like Teamspeak, Discord or anything similar that you can chat in.

These chats are typically organised into channels.

Now is the word *channel* (So the word when it’s used for Teamspeak or chatting or similar) translated to *Kanal* or not?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29697/which-one-is-more-appropiate-chatroom-vs-chatraum

Comment: @close_voters: OP is not asking for a translation, but about the appropriateness of using the English term in a German context. The similar *chatroom vs. chatroom* question linked above was generously upvoted.

Comment: Hier kann auch auf Deutsch gefragt werden.

Comment: Nach meiner Erfahrung ist es normalerweise nicht übersetzt (auch nicht in den deutschen Versionen der entsprechenden Software).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no fixed rule as to when we have to translate an English technical term or when not.

So in this case we can have a look at how the makers of Teamspeak do it:

> Bei Teamspeak 3 hat man die Möglichkeit, eigene Icons für eine Gruppe oder einen **Channel** zu setzen.<sup>[Temaspeak support](http://www.teamspeak.de/support/antworten/182617/Icons/a1/Wie_setze_ich_Gruppen_oder_Channelicons.html)</sup>

In addition to this most other support pages or forums also do not translate *Channel* to German. So in the context of Teamspeak it is safe to use *Channel* as a technical term in an otherwise German text.

Answer (score 1):

Channel means "Kanal" in German.

The TeamSpeak developers usually say either "Kanal" or channel. Both is fine. I and many people using TeamSpeak prefer channel over "Kanal".

It's up to you and it depends a bit whether you're talking to a guy fluent in English or a native German bad at English.

The German gaming community is using TeamSpeak and they are fluent in English so they would say channel. When they had to explain TeamSpeak to their grandpa they'd probably say "Kanal".

Answer (score 0):

The answer must be split into two parts, depending on whether we are dealing with a voice channel (Teamspeak’s standard) or a text channel (what I use most on Discord).

For a voice channel, you can either leave *channel* entirely untranslated or you can use *Kanal* analogously to [*Funkkanal*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funkkanal). Thus, both the following are possible:

> Wir treffen uns dann um halb fünf im Raid-Kanal. Push-to-Talk an machen!
>
> Verdammt, ich finde den Channel nicht mehr, dabei will ich doch mitreden!

For a text channel, I would be hesitant to use either word. Instead, I would be inclined to interpret the text channels as a chat and thus the single channel would be a chat room. And the room can also be translated:

> In welchem Chat kann ich dumme Witze reißen?
>
> Dafür haben wir einen extra Ignorier-mich-Chatraum.
>
> Und in das Chatroom kommt jeder rein?
>
> Ja, aber nicht mehr raus.

I will acknowledge, however, that [Discord’s official German help page](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/de/articles/206143877-Wie-setze-ich-einen-Rollen-exklusiven-Kanal-auf) uses the term *Kanal* for text channels, which had me looking twice whether they really meant text.

Answer (score -2):

No, nobody translates it into "Kanal", as "Kanal" is associated with artificial rivers, or TV broadcasting, or testing aerodynamics - but never with a chat. Chat rooms however are translated into "Raum" - German speaking IRC users usually refer to i.e. "Raumliste".

Comment: Wie wärs stattdessen mit *Chat*? Auch wenns ebenso anekdotisch ist, hab ich *Raum* nie in dieser Bedeutung **aktiv** gebraucht gesehen (holprige Übersetzungen von Programmnachrichten ausgeschlossen). *Raumliste* ist mir vollkommen fremd - womit die Generalisierung übertrieben ist.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=chat+raumliste&tbm=isch bestätigt meine Erfahrungen.

Comment: holprige Übersetzung, teilweise ein und dasselbe Programm.. Ich habe nie gesehen dass jemand das **aktiv** benutzt, also **geschrieben** hat. Wie der Übersetzer das nennt, sagt nichts über die Allgemeinheit aus, welche du in deiner Antwort beschreibst (siehe auch klassische Microsoft-Übersetzungen á la * **der** Firewall*). Natürlich kann es genug Leute geben, die dennoch *Raumliste* sagen/schreiben, aber eben bei weitem nicht alle.

Comment: Es ist eine wahrscheinlichere Übersetzung als zu "Kanal" und auch naheliegend, wenn die englischsprachige Bezeichnung "Room" ist, wie ich mit meiner Antwort sagen wollte: https://www.google.de/search?q=chat+raum&tbm=isch - eine holprige Übersetzung ist "Room" zu "Raum" keineswegs. Und weil zu "Channel" keine existiert, mündet das auch mitunter in "Raum".